# Where can I unload my ill-gotten goods?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Being the greedy thief that I am, I've plundered the citizens of Gorhart and grabbed just about everything that isn't nailed down. However, they must brand their initials into everything there, because none of the shopkeepers in Gorhart will buy my stolen goods.

In general, what types of merchants will purchase my stolen goods, and more specifically, where's the first place in the game that will let me offload them?

Comment: In a strange turn of events, the stolen stuff reappeared in my junk bag after fast traveling. So yeah, definitely a bug on my end. Hahaha

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll edit that part out of this question then. Good to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any merchant will buy stolen items from you if you have maxed out your mercantilism skill tree. This requires at *minimum*, level 18, and is probably not something you should shoot for right off the bat.

If you want to sell your stolen items before that, you'll need to find a fence. There's one at [Star Camp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50056/336).

Answer (score 5):

You can sell stolen items to the fence at Star camp. Its relatively close to the starter town. This video shows you where and how.